# How does Heat Fixing make cells stick to a slide?

Tags: bacteriology, experiment, staining

Regarding Gram Straining, my college instructor told us how we pass the slide with the bacteria on a bunsen burner 3-4 times and it fixes the bacteria so that they don't get washed away with water. How does the heat fix the bacteria that on the slide?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Have you ever put a peice of meat into a searing hot pan and had it stick? That piece of meat is thick, yet it still sticks, Imagine if it were only a few cells thick, What are the odds it would wash off with water?

Comment: I haven't done that but yeah I have seen the meat stick to the pan but why does that happen? Why does the meat or the cells stick to the surface because of heat? What is the science behind it?

Comment: It's because meat and skin and cells are made of (not exclusively but enough) protein, and heat denatures protein.

Comment: So why does it stick because of the denaturing of the protein?

Answer (score 0):

I grasped this concept from bob1, a notable member of this site , that the term heat fixation is misleading, as heat is not what actually fixes cells in this method, it's dryness that does. In other words, anything that will get these cells to dry will fix them.

I add that generally, the actual culmination for cell fixation resides in denaturing and precipitating proteins. Drying does that. So does methanol.

Now you have two options:

1- Drying: The most reliable way to do that is air-drying, that is, leaving the slide anywhere for atleast 20 minutes or 30 minutes to be sure.

2- Methanol fixation

Heat fixation, or to say it correctly dry fixation by direct heat, is a bad method because you can easily pass the endpoint and the result of doing so is disastrous [*].

--

[*] https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6201316/